# Removing multiple characters and joining in pandas columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to format this string but excluding the characters: **(**  **)**

```
My_name (1)
Your_name (2)
```

Desired output:

```
My_name_ID_1
Your_name_ID_2
```

This is a column of my dataframe.I tried replacing but only one character at a time, and I also would like to join afterward.

Can I join and replace already those both characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with `str.replace`:

```
s.str.replace(r'(\w+)\s+\(([^\)])\)', r'\1_ID_\2')
```

```
0      My_name_ID_1
1    Your_name_ID_2
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

An alternative is:

```
s.str.replace(r'\s+\(([^\)])\)', r'_ID_\1')
```

If you'd like to be less explicit.

---

***Regex Explanation***

```
(                          # matching group 1
  \w+                      # matches any word character
)                          
\s+                        # matches one or more spaces
\(                         # matches the character (
(                          # matching group 2
  [^\)]                    # matches any character that IS NOT )
) 
\)                         # matches the character )
```

Comment: awesome! I had to pause to understand the expression as it is not so easy at once! thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I noticed that it is working for most of my IDS but some of them are not joining it as the expression follows. e.g: NAMED_NO_DI_BACK (26)

Answer (score 2):

you can also use :

```
s.str.replace(r"\(.*\)","").str.strip()+"_ID_"+s.str.replace(r'[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*', '')
```

However, the answer by @user3483203 is better. :)